# Is 'Search List Item' the best name for link and description on a results page?

Tags: search-results

I'm designing the Search Result Page and each result has a link and description similar to a search engine results page.

What is the best way to refer to this element? Should I call this 'Search List Item'? or 'Simple Data List'?

[image]

Comment: Downvoters, this question is so unclear, how could you possibly know if there's any value to be extracted?  Ask for clarification before reaching for the down vote button.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking what to call the link and description? and your options currently are 'Search List Item' and 'Data List Item'?

Comment: Thanks @dennislees for message to downvoters. my question mainly about knowing the experience. what is actually the term name for those. i guess is that Search List Item. its specific block name. what is the common name for this is kind of similar blocks

Comment: Perhaps others may know different, but I don't think it really matters. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It doesn't really matter**

When the name of an element is unclear or obvious, it matters less what something is called than how consistent you are with it.

**Be Consistent, Pick & Stick**

Pick something sensible and reasonable. "Search List Item" works. So does "Result". The key thing is that you make it clear (ideally in a glossary, if you have one) what the label means, and that everyone involved should use that label consistently.